# Agument list files API call with createdTime attribute in Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I'd like to retrieve all the resources (files and folder) via the [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
API call with the createdTime attribute included.

Standard response doesn't include the createdTime key described in the [resource representation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) so I've added the fields query parameter with the value createdTime (there's an [open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759632) related which says so but referring to API v2 while I'm using API v3).

API call I'm doing is the following:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=createdTime
```

with proper authentication.

A 400 status code response is returned with the following body:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalidParameter",
                "message": "Invalid field selection createdTime",
                "locationType": "parameter",
                "location": "fields"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid field selection createdTime"
    }
}
```

What's the correct way of using the fields query parameter?

Comment: After looking at [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72007653) only way I found was to set the fields query parameter with value *.
So API call is something like https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the full response you can do the following  [test here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list?fields=*)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=*
```

If you just want the create date you can also do [test here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list?fields=files(createdTime)&_h=7&)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files(createdTime)
```

You can read more about this in [Partial response](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/performance#partial-response)

Comment: I was missing the `files` value, where is it documented?

Comment: All fields does is let you split up the response.  just check the filelistresponse it contains a list of file s